# Different access methods to Pyro Paramstore give different results

Tags: machine-learning, probabilistic-programming, pyro.ai

I am following the Pyro introductory tutorial in [forecasting](https://pyro.ai/examples/forecasting_i.html), and trying to access the learned parameters after training the model, I get different results using different access methods for some of them (while getting identical results for others).

Here is the stripped-down **reproducible** code from the tutorial:

```python
import torch
import pyro
import pyro.distributions as dist
from pyro.contrib.examples.bart import load_bart_od
from pyro.contrib.forecast import ForecastingModel, Forecaster

pyro.enable_validation(True)
pyro.clear_param_store()

pyro.__version__
# '1.3.1'
torch.__version__
# '1.5.0+cu101'

# import & prepare the data
dataset = load_bart_od()
T, O, D = dataset["counts"].shape
data = dataset["counts"][:T // (24 * 7) * 24 * 7].reshape(T // (24 * 7), -1).sum(-1).log()
data = data.unsqueeze(-1)
T0 = 0              # begining
T2 = data.size(-2)  # end
T1 = T2 - 52        # train/test split

# define the model class
class Model1(ForecastingModel):

    def model(self, zero_data, covariates):
        data_dim = zero_data.size(-1)  
        feature_dim = covariates.size(-1)

        bias = pyro.sample("bias", dist.Normal(0, 10).expand([data_dim]).to_event(1))
        weight = pyro.sample("weight", dist.Normal(0, 0.1).expand([feature_dim]).to_event(1))
        prediction = bias + (weight * covariates).sum(-1, keepdim=True)
        assert prediction.shape[-2:] == zero_data.shape

        noise_scale = pyro.sample("noise_scale", dist.LogNormal(-5, 5).expand([1]).to_event(1))
        noise_dist = dist.Normal(0, noise_scale)

        self.predict(noise_dist, prediction)

# fit the model
pyro.set_rng_seed(1)
pyro.clear_param_store()
time = torch.arange(float(T2)) / 365
covariates = torch.stack([time], dim=-1)
forecaster = Forecaster(Model1(), data[:T1], covariates[:T1], learning_rate=0.1)
```

So far so good; now, I want to inspect the learned latent parameters stored in `Paramstore`. Seems there are more than one ways to do this; using the `get_all_param_names()` method:

```python
for name in pyro.get_param_store().get_all_param_names():
    print(name, pyro.param(name).data.numpy())
```

I get

```python
AutoNormal.locs.bias [14.585433]
AutoNormal.scales.bias [0.00631594]
AutoNormal.locs.weight [0.11947815]
AutoNormal.scales.weight [0.00922901]
AutoNormal.locs.noise_scale [-2.0719821]
AutoNormal.scales.noise_scale [0.03469057]
```

But using the `named_parameters()` method:

```python
pyro.get_param_store().named_parameters()
```

gives the same values for the location (`locs`) parameters, but **different values** for all `scales` ones:

```python
dict_items([
('AutoNormal.locs.bias', Parameter containing: tensor([14.5854], requires_grad=True)), 
('AutoNormal.scales.bias', Parameter containing: tensor([-5.0647], requires_grad=True)), 
('AutoNormal.locs.weight', Parameter containing: tensor([0.1195], requires_grad=True)), 
('AutoNormal.scales.weight', Parameter containing: tensor([-4.6854], requires_grad=True)),
('AutoNormal.locs.noise_scale', Parameter containing: tensor([-2.0720], requires_grad=True)), 
('AutoNormal.scales.noise_scale', Parameter containing: tensor([-3.3613], requires_grad=True))
])
```

How is this possible? According to the [documentation](http://docs.pyro.ai/en/latest/parameters.html), `Paramstore` is a simple key-value store; and there are only these six keys in it:

```python
pyro.get_param_store().get_all_param_names() # .keys() method gives identical result
# result
dict_keys([
'AutoNormal.locs.bias',
'AutoNormal.scales.bias', 
'AutoNormal.locs.weight', 
'AutoNormal.scales.weight', 
'AutoNormal.locs.noise_scale', 
'AutoNormal.scales.noise_scale'])
```

so, there is no way that one method access one set of items and the other a different one.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the situation, as revealed in the [Github thread](https://github.com/pyro-ppl/pyro/issues/2470) I opened in parallel with this question...

`Paramstore` is no more *just* a simple key-value store - it also performs constraint transformations; quoting a Pyro developer from the above link:

> here's some historical background. The `ParamStore` was originally just a key-value store. Then we added support for constrained parameters; this introduced a new layer of separation between user-facing constrained values and internal unconstrained values. We created a new dict-like user-facing interface that exposed only constrained values, but to keep backwards compatibility with old code we kept the old interface around. The two interfaces are distinguished in the source files [...] but as you observe it looks like we forgot to mark the old interface as DEPRECATED.
>
> I guess in clarifying docs we should:
>
> 1. clarify that the ParamStore is no longer a simple key-value store
>      but also performs constraint transforms;
> 2. mark all "old" style interface methods as DEPRECATED;
> 3. remove "old" style interface usage from examples and tutorials.

As a consequence, it turns out that, while `pyro.param()` returns the results in the constrained (user-facing) space, the older method `named_parameters()` returns the unconstrained (i.e. for internal use only) values, hence the apparent discrepancy.

It's not difficult to verify indeed that the `scales` values returned by the two methods above are related by a logarithmic transformation:

```python
import numpy as np
items = list(pyro.get_param_store().named_parameters())  # unconstrained space

i = 0
for name in pyro.get_param_store().keys():  
  if 'scales' in name:
    temp = np.log(
                  pyro.param(name).item()  # constrained space
                 )
    print(temp, items[i][1][0].item() , np.allclose(temp, items[i][1][0].item()))
  i+=1

# result:
-5.027793402915326 -5.0277934074401855 True
-4.600319371162187 -4.6003193855285645 True
-3.3920585732532835 -3.3920586109161377 True
```

Why does this discrepancy affect only `scales` parameters? That's because `scales` (i.e. essentially *variances*) are by definition constrained to be positive; that doesn't hold for `locs` (i.e. means), which are not constrained, hence the two representations coincide for them.

As a [result](https://github.com/pyro-ppl/pyro/pull/2471) of the question above, a new bullet has now been added in the `Paramstore` [documentation](http://docs.pyro.ai/en/latest/parameters.html#module-pyro.params.param_store), giving a relevant hint:

> in general parameters are associated with both *constrained* and *unconstrained* values. for example, under the hood a parameter that is constrained to be positive is represented as an unconstrained tensor in log space.

as well as in the [documentation](http://docs.pyro.ai/en/latest/parameters.html#pyro.params.param_store.ParamStoreDict.named_parameters) of the `named_parameters()` method of the old interface:

> Note that, in the event the parameter is constrained, *unconstrained_value* is in the unconstrained space implicitly used by the constraint.

Answer (score 2):

`pyro.param()` [returns transformed parameters](https://github.com/pyro-ppl/pyro/blob/dev/pyro/params/param_store.py#L112) in this case to the positive reals for `scales`.